# How to add hreflag tags to Prestashop to prevent Google Search Console warnings

Tags: seo, google-search-console, hreflang, prestashop

I have a Prestashop multi languages site, and I started to notice some warning in the webmaster tools of Google that my site is lacking hreflang tags.

Is there something in Prestashop to handle the hreflang or can it be easily implemented in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I found you also here! Well, Prestashop is actually lacking any Hreflang handling, but if you are interested, I've developed a module that adds the hreflang links for several page types.
You can find it here:

http://www.matteobononi.it/prestashop_module_hreflang.php

the module is working for index, categories pages, product pages, cms pages, manufactures, and other page types. it adds the links only if the page exists in some other language, and it takes the ISO and language codes from those you have inserted in the localization settings (in the Prestashop admin).

be sure to read about ISO codes and languages codes on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hreflang

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know - hreflang is  link tag  in meta section.
install module to change meta ?   c'mon !!! It's like shooting to mosquito with cannon.

HTML (meta tags) are(should be)  in themes/{theme  name}/header.tpl  (for default theme is themes/default-bootstrap/header.tpl ). Edit  hreflang (metatags) there  , clear cache and  should  be ok

Comment: Michal, doing this you will make the hreflang tag dependant of your theme, which is not a good idea !!!
You can also have a multishop instance of PrestaShop, using a shared theme, and might want to add hreflang only on a few shops
That's why modules are made... make PrestaShop... modulable :)

Comment: Not to mention that PS has different methods to calculate the URLs in different languages, so you should put a lot of logic into a template, in this case, is far more better to shoot with a cannon to that mosquito.